# Is it necessary to set a function with always_inline attribution when the function would work maybe once?

Tags: c++, spi, inline

I'm going through a library for the ILI9488 running by SPI and want to copy this library in my version.

In the beginning of the source file, there's a guard for the `SPI_HAS_TRANSACTION` that if the library would run in Arduino compiler then it would use the SPI functions, otherwise it should run from another platform SPI libraries.

Library link:
[jaretburkett / ILI9488](https://github.com/jaretburkett/ILI9488)

This is the part of code I have questions about:

```
// If the SPI library has transaction support, these functions
// establish settings and protect from interference from other
// libraries.  Otherwise, they simply do nothing.
#ifdef SPI_HAS_TRANSACTION
static inline void spi_begin(void) __attribute__((always_inline));
static inline void spi_begin(void) {
#if defined (ARDUINO_ARCH_ARC32)
  // max speed!
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(16000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
#else
    // max speed!
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(24000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
#endif
}
static inline void spi_end(void) __attribute__((always_inline));
static inline void spi_end(void) {
  SPI.endTransaction();
}
#else
#define spi_begin()
#define spi_end()
#endif
```

My questions:

1. why the programmer first declare the function in source file not in header file ?
2. why to use `always_inline` attribution for a function that's is most the time used once in program file and it's not likely to be used many times during operating time ?
3. what does this define means `ARDUINO_ARCH_ARC32` and where to find it ? I searched in all files in arduino folders and didn't find it. Is it dedicated for fast boards or the usual 16MHz arduino boards ?

---

Edit:

I want to add another question for the same library.

This function content:

```
void ILI9488::spiwrite(uint8_t c) {

  //Serial.print("0x"); Serial.print(c, HEX); Serial.print(", ");

  if (hwSPI) {
#if defined (__AVR__)
  #ifndef SPI_HAS_TRANSACTION
    uint8_t backupSPCR = SPCR;
    SPCR = mySPCR;
  #endif
    SPDR = c;
    while(!(SPSR & _BV(SPIF)));
  #ifndef SPI_HAS_TRANSACTION
    SPCR = backupSPCR;
  #endif
#else
    SPI.transfer(c);
#endif
  } else {
#if defined(ESP8266) || defined (ARDUINO_ARCH_ARC32)
    for(uint8_t bit = 0x80; bit; bit >>= 1) {
      if(c & bit) {
    digitalWrite(_mosi, HIGH);
      } else {
    digitalWrite(_mosi, LOW);
      }
      digitalWrite(_sclk, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(_sclk, LOW);
    }
#else
    // Fast SPI bitbang swiped from LPD8806 library
    for(uint8_t bit = 0x80; bit; bit >>= 1) {
      if(c & bit) {
    //digitalWrite(_mosi, HIGH);
    *mosiport |=  mosipinmask;
      } else {
    //digitalWrite(_mosi, LOW);
    *mosiport &= ~mosipinmask;
      }
      //digitalWrite(_sclk, HIGH);
      *clkport |=  clkpinmask;
      //digitalWrite(_sclk, LOW);
      *clkport &= ~clkpinmask;
    }
#endif
  }
}
```

what I understood from this is that the programmer wants the library to be more versatile to support AVR chips programmer by another IDE than Arduino, also supports ESP8266 and anything else should be handled by softSPI, actually pretty smart coding I guess.

My question here, is does `#if defined (__AVR__)` checks for either AVR/Arduino in general and when specifies `SPI_HAS_TRANSACTION` means Arduino SPI library specifically ? right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. why the programmer first declare the function in source file not in header file ?

the declarion is for the inline attribute. the function should be used only in this cpp.

> 2. why to use always_inline attribution for a function that's is most the time used once in program file and it's not likely to be used many
>    times during operating time ?

there are 14 occurrences of transaction start and it is called before every SPI communication commands set in the library. see [my answer about beginTransaction](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/79728/when-is-spi-begintransaction-required/79737#79737)

> 3. what does this define means ARDUINO_ARCH_ARC32 and where to find it ? I searched in all files in arduino folders and didn't find it. Is it
>    dedicated for fast boards or the usual 16MHz arduino boards ?

[the architecture define](https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/library-specification/#working-with-multiple-architectures) is generated by the builder from selected board's boards package folder name. ARC32 architecture is the Intel Arduino 101 boards package.

EDIT (answer to edited part of the question):

> My question here, is does `#if defined (__AVR__)` checks for either
> AVR/Arduino in general and when specifies SPI_HAS_TRANSACTION means
> Arduino SPI library specifically ? right ?

`__AVR__` is defined in avrlibc, the toolchain for AVR microcontrolers. Arduino uses avrlibc for AVR MCUs. It is not recommended to check `__AVR__`. The AVR family of MCU is now large with different peripherals so checking `__AVR__` should be really restricted to CPU matters.

Every Arduino 'architecture' has its own SPI library. The transactions support was added later so not all implementations of the SPI library support transactions. To declare transactions availability in SPI library Arduino defined the SPI_HAS_TRANSACTION define.

Comment: Thank you for the links ! Really helpful. But I have a question, where the defines are located ? Also what speeds are related to ? like `ARC32` has 16MHz so which other chips have 24MHz ?

Comment: other SPI libraries use max SPI speed of the architecture if higher is requested. the architecture (and board) defines are specified as -D option on compiler command line created by the arduino builder based on platform.txt entries as -DARDUINO_{build.board} -DARDUINO_ARCH_{build.arch}

Comment: first where to find `platform.txt` ? second, I understood that the defines are saved in `platform.txt` file and passed with -D option during compilation, so the compiler put things together in linker stage, right ?

Comment: I want to add another question in the main post, hope you check it.

Comment: I enhanced the answer. platform.txt is in boards package folder as it is installed by Arduino IDE (please don't ask a follow up question for this. it is a different topic).  you can read the Arduino platform documentation here https://arduino.github.io/arduino-cli/platform-specification/

Comment: thanks for the support

Answer (score 1):

1. The function is only used in the library, and not part of the "API" of that library. Kind of like a private function.
2. Both functions are both being called 14 times inside the source code of this library. But in the larger scheme of things, it doesn't add a lot. But why not add it and maybe save a few bytes, and a few clock cycles.
3. The `ARDUINO_ARCH_ARC32` is for the Arduino 101 board (Intel Curie processor).

Comment: I'm replying to your answer points.

1. Yes, the programmer defined a guard with two functions; `static inline void spi_begin(void)` and `static inline void spi_end(void)` which include a call for SPI library.

2. How to save few bytes with inline ? I learned that it saves clock cycles but not space.

3. So actually, I don't have to use `ARDUINO_ARCH_ARC32` when I'm using nano or uno boards ? right ?

Comment: It's been more than two months. I don't remember what this is about.

Comment: It's about the use of SPI begin function that is used in a library and put in inline mode.

Comment: I don't have time to dive into you question again, at the moment. So I'm not able to answer your followup. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind reply, you're right, it's been a lot of time for anyone other than me to remember what this topic is about, I'm sorry for my unbalanced follow-up question, I really should open a new thread.

Answer (score 1):

Here I am only addressing question number 2. The others have already
complete answers.

The choice to whether a function should be inlined or not is a
speed/size trade-off. There is a cost to calling a function. On AVR, for
example, the `call` instruction takes 4 CPU cycles, and `ret` takes
another 4. Inlining the function removes this cost. On the other hand,
you end up with as many copies of the function as places where it is
inlined, and this in turn costs flash memory.

The compiler is usually smart enough to make wise decision regarding
function inlining. In this case, it is not obvious what decision it
would make on its own. On the one hand, the function is used multiple
times in the code, which makes a good case *against* inlining it. On the
other hand, the body of the function is tiny: only setting up some
registers (the two parameters of `SPIClass::beginTransaction()`,
including the implicit `this`) and [jumping to another function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call),
so the cost of inlining is small.

For this library, the programmer happened to have a strong opinion on
this matter, and he though inlining was really the best option. Also, he
did not thrust the compiler to make the good decision. This is the
reason why he used the gcc extension:

```cpp
__attribute__((always_inline))
```

And no, it is not necessary, it is just an optimization choice.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, after some time; just now, I opened this thread and read your answer with more deep attention, and got your answer understood at a very good level. I learned that if I didn't use `__attribute__((always_inline))` then the compiler would decide if the function is inlined or not. That's an important information I learned about inlining. Also, the inlined function should be small enough not to take a lot of flash space, big functions should be called normally.